# delete image from docker registry v2

Tags: docker

the Docker Registry v2 has an API endpoint to delete an image

```
DELETE /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
```

https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md#deleting-an-image

However the doc says:

> For deletes, reference must be a digest or the delete will fail.

Indeed, using a `tag` does not work and returns a `405 Operation Not Supported`

The problem is, there doesn't seem to be any endpoint to get the `digest` of an image.

The endpoints to list images, and tags only list those.

Trying to get the manifest with

```
GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
```

using the `tag` as `<reference>`I see that a `Docker-Content-Digest` header is set with a `digest` which the doc says is

> Docker-Content-Digest:    Digest of the targeted content
>   for the request.

while the body contains a bunch of `blobSum: <digest>`

If I try using the Header digest value, with

```
GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
```

and the `digest` as `<reference>`, I get a `404`.

the `digest` looks like: `sha256:6367f164d92eb69a7f4bf4cab173e6b21398f94984ea1e1d8addc1863f4ed502`

and I tried with and without the `sha256` prefix. but no luck

**So how am I supposed to get the `digest` of the image I want to delete, to delete it?**

Comment: usefule doc for you : https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1821

Comment: useful indeed... but kinda crazy that this is the only way to get the digest id.

Answer (score 2):

```
curl -u login:password -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X GET https://registry.private.com/v2/<name>/manifests/<tag>
```

json > config > digest

Answer (score 0):

Not a trivial operation in Docker API right now but I hope this procedure helps:

1. Create a file and give it a name, for me it will be `delete-image.sh`:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   # Inspired by: https://gist.github.com/jaytaylor/86d5efaddda926a25fa68c263830dac1

   set -o errexit

   if [ -z "$1" ]
     then
       echo "Error: The image name arg is mandatory"
       exit 1
   fi


   registry='localhost:5000'
   name=$1

   curl -v -sSL -X DELETE "http://${registry}/v2/${name}/manifests/$(
       curl -sSL -I \
           -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
               "http://${registry}/v2/${name}/manifests/$(
               curl -sSL "http://${registry}/v2/${name}/tags/list" | jq -r '.tags[0]'
           )" \
       | awk '$1 == "Docker-Content-Digest:" { print $2 }' \
       | tr -d $'\r' \
   )"
   ```
2. Give the permission to that file so that it can be executed;

   ```sh
   sudo chmod u+x ./delete-image.sh
   ./delete-image.sh <your-image-name>
   ```
3. After deleting the image, collect the garbage;

   ```sh
   docker exec -it registry.localhost bin/registry \
       garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
   ```
4. Now delete the folder for that image (and I'm assuming that you created a volume previously);

   ```sh
   sudo rm -rf ${HOME}/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/<your-image-name>
   ```
5. If you have not created a volume, you may have to enter the container to delete that folder. But, in any case, it's a good idea to restart the container;

   ```sh
   docker restart registry.localhost
   ```

**Procedure not recommended for production environments**.

I hope that we will have better support for these operations natively in the Docker API in the future.